# Is there a U.S. or Canadian yeshiva that offers a Smicha program where the Rosh Kollel can accommodate the deaf?

Tags: product-recommendation, chutz-laaretz, yeshiva-school, deaf

My son is deaf. I am looking for a Smicha program for him where the Rosh Yeshiva has experience dealing with and accommodating the deaf. My son has a cochlear implant and has SOME hearing, so he does not need an interpreter, per-se, though that would help. Does anyone know of a place and / or refer me to someone I can email or speak to?

Comment: When I was in NIRC, there were a handful of deaf bochrim.  Shiur klali was translated into ASL, and there was even a lunch-break class to learn sign-language.  I don't know if that helps you.

Comment: Offhand, do you know if they were high school or Kollel (in Smicha)?

Comment: they were post-high school.  At least one was in Kollel.  A smicha "program" doesn't really exist at NIRC - you learn, and if you happen to learn the material necessary for semicha, you take a test.

Comment: @YEZ- appreciate if you can post name of contact and phone # and/or email.

Comment: NIRC contact? Main office - 410-484-7200, you could ask to speak to R' Sheftl Neuberger.  I guess.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/13426

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The one high school Yeshiva in North America for the deaf is Yeshivas Nefesh Dovid (http://www.nefeshdovid.com/) located in Toronto.  The Rosh Yeshiva, Rabbi Chaim Tzvi Kakon, himself is deaf and got his S'micha from Ner Israel Rabbinical College in Baltimore, MD.

Comment: Thanks, I know Rabbi Kakon. I speak to him, frequently, I wasn't aware that Ner accomodates deaf. Will have to investigate, further.